# xml file with the same tag name and diffrent values

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i m working on XML and getting its values in asp.net grid. my xml have same columns name and different values so every time its read only one record. anyone help please?

following is my XML structure

```
    <ind>
        <Name>
            <value> a1 </value>
        </Name>
        <Name>
            <value> a2 </value>
        </Name>
        <Name>
            <value> a3 </value>
        </Name>
        <Name>
            <value> a4 </value>
        </Name>
    </ind>
```

Comment: post the code here, how you retrieve or generate this xml

Comment: xmldoc.Load("file.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ind/name"); 
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                

                dtrow["Name1"] = node["name"][value].InnerText;

               
                dtrow["Name2"] = node["name"][value].InnerText;
                dtrow["Name3"] = node["name"][value].InnerText;
} im using this type of approach

Comment: You can modify your question and add your formatted code. If you load into DataTable, I modified my answer to add to datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq To Xml

```
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
    xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var result = xdoc.Descendants("Name");

     foreach (XElement item in result) {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Value);
     }
```

[Demo Example online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B5iDfP)

**Update**

From the comment of OP, you add the xml elements to a DataTable.

The modified version to fill a DataTable:

```
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
    //xdoc= XDocument.Load("file.xml"); read from file
    xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //read from string
    List<string> Names = new List<string>();
    var result = xdoc.Descendants("Name");

     foreach (var item in result)           
         Names.Add(item.Value);


    //create datatable

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("table");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name3", typeof(string));        

    //fill datatable
    DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow(); 
    dtrow["Name1"]=Names[0];
    dtrow["Name2"]=Names[1];
    dtrow["Name3"]=Names[2];
    dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

    //test datatable
     Console.WriteLine("Name1:{0}, Name2:{1},Name3:{2}", 
                      dt.Rows[0]["Name1"],
                      dt.Rows[0]["Name2"],
                      dt.Rows[0]["Name3"]);
```

> output
>   Name1: a1 , Name2: a2 ,Name3: a3

[Demo Example online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KjRNwJ)